# Laravel Facade not being loaded

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I started with a fresh installation of Laravel and then did the following...

I filled in the config/workbench.php file with my info: -

```
return array('name' => 'My Name', 'email' => 'fullysick@email.com');
```

I ran the artisan command: -

```
php artisan workbench dicksmith/curl --resources
```

Everything reported success.  It installed dependencies etc.

I populated the app.php file with the necessary service provider and alias information.  My code can be seen here -> http://paste.laravel.com/wFj

I'm struggling to think why it may not be loading through the Facade accessor.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried to add service name in `CurlServiceProvider::provides()` method?

Comment: The service is loading fine using the $app global, so it's not a service issue.  The problem is coming from the Facade (somewhere).

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

I just needed to have the Facades directory located inside the package.

A stupid, stupid, stupid, stupid mistake on my behalf.  2 days lost... I feel sheepish.